# Issue running brew doctor command in command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, homebrew

I'm getting this problem when running brew doctor in Command Line - any ideas?

```
 Jack:~ JackSymons$ brew doctor
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config

Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.
```

**Also when running gem update --system, I get the following:**

```
Jack:~ JackSymons$ gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

Comment: Have you tried `brew install openssl`?

Comment: That's helped with that issue - thanks!